# angular component one-time binding from $http shows undefined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-http, angularjs-components

I'm new to Angular.  I'm trying to use components (1.6).  In the parent, I have an `$http.get` that gets data from a service and then assigns the response to a `$scope` variable.  That scope variable is passed to a child component using one-way binding `<`. In the JavaScript, if I alert the variable passed in, I get "undefined", however, the html template in the child does show the variable.  It's like there is a race condition happening and I don't know how to tell it to wait until the data from the service is loaded.

In my parent.js:

```
(function (angular) {
    'use strict';
    $http.get("http://localhost:52422/api/PayOffYourCc")
    .then(function mySucces(response) {
        $scope.baseline = response.data;

    }
    ,
    function myError(respone) {
        $scope.baseline = response.statusText;

    }
    );
})(window.angular);
```

In my parent HTML template:

```
<thermometer baseline="baseline"></thermometer>
```

In my child component:

```
(function (angular) {
    'use strict';

    function drawChart(baselineVal) {
        alert(baselineVal);
    }

    function ThermometerController($scope) {
        var ctrl = this;
        ctrl.$onInit = function () {
            drawChart(ctrl.baseline);
        };


    }

    angular.module('payOffYourCcApp').component('thermometer', {
        templateUrl: '../PayOffYourCC/partials/thermometer.html',
        transclude: true,
        controller: ThermometerController,
        bindings: {
            baseline: '<'
        }
    });
})(window.angular);
```

In my child html template:

```
<div>
    baseline:{{$ctrl.baseline}}
</div>
```

In the html, `{{$ctrl.baseline}}` is displayed fine, but when I alert it in the .js, it's `undefined`.  Why is that?  How can I make sure the `{{$ctrl.baseline}}` is in scope before the javascript loads?

Comment: Once the http callback function completes and a value has been assigned to baseline, it triggers a digest cycle which updates your view accordingly. The alert operation happens synchronically though - before the http operation even has a chance to complete

Comment: Thank you very much for all the solutions.  I understand it much better now, however, I've decided to give react.js a go.  I'm still having issues with http call backs and race conditions, but I'll let you know how I get on.

Comment: Actually, had other similar issues with React.  It's all to do with component life cycle.  I've gone back to using Angular - thanks to the answer given below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `$onChanges` life-cycle hook:

```
function ThermometerController($scope) {
    var ctrl = this;
    /* REPLACE THIS
    ctrl.$onInit = function () {
        drawChart(ctrl.baseline);
    }; */
    // WITH THIS
    ctrl.$onChanges = function (changesObj) {
        if (changesObj.baseline && changesObj.baseline.currentValue) {
            drawChart(changesObj.baseline.currentValue);
        };
    };
}
```

The controller needs to wait for the data to come from the server. By using the $onChanges life-cycle hook, the `drawChart` function will be called when the data becomes available and will be called on subsequent updates.

For more information, see [AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API Reference - Life-Cycle Hooks](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#life-cycle-hooks).

Answer (score 0):

With Angular component, you should privilege communication from the child back to the parent since it allows a very cheap binding (`&`)

You can communicate from the parent to the child but it is more expensive (`=`).
I will give you an example on how to do it.
It is a not tested solution but you should have the idea.

You should change your parent to have a child api to transmit the data :

JS Parent :

```
(function (angular) {
    'use strict';
    $http.get("http://localhost:52422/api/PayOffYourCc")
    .then(function mySucces(response) {
        $scope.baseline = response.data;
        $ctrl.apiChild.transmit(response.data);
    }
    ,
    function myError(respone) {
        $scope.baseline = response.statusText;
    }
    );
})(window.angular);
```

HTML Parent :

```
<thermometer api="$ctrl.apiChild"></thermometer>
```

Change your child to have a function to receive the data from the parent and also change the binding to `"="` :

JS Child :

```
(function (angular) {

'use strict';

function drawChart(baselineVal) {
    alert(baselineVal);
}

function ThermometerController($scope) {
    var ctrl = this;
    ctrl.$onInit = function () {
        drawChart(ctrl.baseline);
        ctrl.api = {};
        ctrl.api.transmit = ctrl.transmitData;
    };

   this.transmitData = function transmitData(data){
        // here you get the data from the parent to the child
   }

}

angular.module('payOffYourCcApp').component('thermometer', {
    templateUrl: '../PayOffYourCC/partials/thermometer.html',
    transclude: true,
    controller: ThermometerController,
    bindings: {
        api : '='
    }
});
})(window.angular);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the result of the fact that $http requests are **asynchronous**. The alert that happens when the child component initializes prints `undefined`, because at that instance the $http request that is retrieving the data has not returned yet. Since you're using `>` binding however, the template in your child component will update with the correct value as soon as the request resolves (which is pretty darn fast), so you don't ever see `undefined` actually printed in the template. In fact, I don't think angular will print undefined, I think it's just blank. So to your eye, it looks like it has the right value right away, when, in reality, it was momentarily undefined while the $http request was resolving.